# Downgrading 9.0.83 Google Play Services manually to avoid DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I got the following log error in [my route tracking activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018234/no-marker-displayed-on-the-map):

> 06-24 18:50:24.488 7128-7759/com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50
>   E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find
>   class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]

After reading some posts and answers (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281942/google-map-api-v2-shows-v-googlesignatureverifier-error-message-in-log) or [this](https://plus.google.com/+ChristopheBeyls/posts/LC2XCSoaVBJ)) about this log error I figured out that it's a known Google Play Services version  9.0.83 issue that causes bugs in some apps that use a GoogleApiClient like mine.

However I didn't test the solution yet. I wanted to downgrade Google Play Services on my Smartphone but Uninstall Updates was greyed out (see Screenshot).

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking the internet for your problem about how to downgrade Google Play Service when the Uninstall Updates was grayed out. I came up with many possible solution. You can check it all and try if this method helps you.

- From this [Stack Exchnge question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103055/how-can-i-uninstall-updates-to-google-play-services-the-buttons-are-greyed-out), you can try the solution here that states:

> If you have the [Android Device
>   manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm)
>   app installed then this can also make the force stop/uninstall updates
>   buttons be disabled.
>
> If you uninstall the Android Device manager app and disable "Android
>   Device Manager" as a device administrator then those options should be
>   enabled.

- From this [forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/delete-disable-downgrade-prevent-update-t3091832), the solution here needs you to download and install System App Remover from the Google Play Store. Just check the forum link to know more about the steps and their information.
- And lastly, you can also check the solution in the discusion of this [forum page](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/how-do-you-uninstall-updates-to-google-play-services.154797/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed the Android Device Manager app but found no possibility to influence the stop/uninstall updates buttons of Google Play Services. Then I tried to apply the [other solution](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/delete-disable-downgrade-prevent-update-t3091832) but  the System App Remover app got no root permission on my Smartphone.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Plus 1.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for my Huawei P8 Lite Android phone like this:

1. I unlocked my bootloader like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_4122929377&feature=iv&src_vid=duquOuRqYDM&v=63L7FBuWFrc)
2. I rooted my phone like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duquOuRqYDM)
3. I succesfully checked with [Root Checker Basic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck) that my phone is rooted
4. I downloaded and installed System App Remover from the Google Play Store.
5. I put my device in Airplane Mode in order to prevent auto upgrade of GPS.
6. I opened System App Remover and select "System App" from the menu.
7. After I found Google Play Services in the list which was marked as "Should keep" I selected it and pressed "Uninstall". I ignored the next warning.
8. Using Settings/Apps, I saw that Google Play Services "Uninstall Updates", and "Disable" Buttons were no longer be grayed out.
9. I pressed "Uninstall Updates"

Here is the result: Downgrade of Google Play Services to 8.1.18

[image]