# Adapting dependencies after downgrading Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, google-maps

What should I compile instead of:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

in my `dependencies` in `build.gradle (Module:app)` when I [downgraded  Google Play Services from 9.0.83 to  8.1.18 manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019820/downgrading-9-0-83-google-play-services-manually-to-avoid-dynamitemodule-failed/38026669#38026669)? My purpose was to avoid this log error:

> 06-24 18:50:24.488 7128-7759/com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50
>   E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find
>   class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]

@Er. Arjun saini : I get this error. (My Manifest file was correctly configured.)

[image]

I'm trying to clean with the following build.gradle now:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        //incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2'
//compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' //remove others instead of

}
```

Compiling works. However my app wants me to update Google Play Services when I move to my route tracking activity. I also see no map anymore.

[image]

I updated Google Play Services after downgrading them and landed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018234/no-marker-displayed-on-the-map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to my Answer by Update the code by this

**First Compile the build with**

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' //remove others instead of

In Your **AndroidManifest.xml** add this lines **android:name**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    >
```

And In your **build.gradle** also add

```
dexOptions {
    //incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. see @Er. Arjun saini  in the original post.

Comment: Thanks again ur answer. Definitly plus one. But my idea of avoiding the original log error by downgrading Google Play Services doesn't seem to work...